# What does + operator do in this line?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to modify a method in an existing module to adapt functionality.
What does + operator do in this line?

```
for line in payment.move_line_ids + expense_sheet.account_move_id.line_ids:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hello M.E.,**

## Solution

- operator of use is concatenation/combine of two `List/String/Tupple`.

## Example

1. Plus(+) Operator use with two `List`

   > a = [1,2,3]
   >   b = [4,5]
   >   print a + b
   >   output = [1,2,3,4,5]
2. `+` operator use with two `String`

   > a = "Vora"
   >   b = " mayur"
   >   print a + b
   >   output = "vora mayur"
3. `+` operator use with two tupple

   > a = (1,2,3)
   >   b = (4,5)
   >   print a + b
   >   output = (1,2,3,4,5)

Answer (score 5):

It [concatenates](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/38c77a521087405d8b42f24c882f19ada0387821/odoo/models.py#L5096-L5098) `account.move.line` records from `payment.move_line_ids` and `expense_sheet.account_move_id.line_ids` into a single recordset, which is then iterated over. Please note that the result of the `__add__` (+) operation might contain duplicates if the same `account.move.line` is present in both operands. If you want to avoid duplicates, use [the `|` (OR) operator](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#set-operations).